# using Sales Force API with C#

Tags: c#, sql, salesforce, soql

I try to use Sales Force API to get some data back. As I found out I can use SOQL instead of SQL that is very similar to SQL.  I have a method that is returning some data. I wonder how I can use store procedure instead of using this statement:

```
SOQL = "select AuthorId,Name, Description,Type from Document";
```

and this is my whole method:

```
   private void getSomeData()
    {
        if (!loggedIn)
        {
            if (!login())
                return;
        }

        QueryResult queryResult = null;

        String SOQL = "";


        SOQL = "select AuthorId,Name, Description,Type from Document";

        queryResult = SfdcBinding.query(SOQL);

        if (queryResult.size > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++)
            {

                Document doc = (Document)queryResult.records[i];

                string Name = doc.Name;
                string Description = doc.Description;
                string Type = doc.Type;
                string AuthorId= doc.AuthorId;



            }



        }
        else
        {
            //put some code in here to handle no records being returned
            string message = "No records returned.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't when directly calling the API. Salesforce doesn't have the concept of a stored procedure in SOQL.

If you really want to use stored procedures there are products available, such as [DBAMP](http://www.forceamp.com/), that make Salesforce appear as a linked server in SQL SERVER. You can then query it using SQL and use stored procedures etc.

Please note that there is a dedicated [stackexchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site for asking Salesforce related questions.